# Asymptotic notation - where am I going wrong

Tags: complexity-theory

I have the following question with the answers given. But I don't understand the answer.

Big theta notation is the tight bound.
Big Oh is the worst case
Big theta is the best case.

So to me the correct responses would be
Its worst case running time is O(n3)
Its best case running time is Ω(n2)
and possibly its running time is Θ (n3) but I'd need to draw the graph out.

However all three of these and in fact **incorrect**.

Why? Is the question incorrect or am I misunderstanding something.

I've been through so many answers on stackoverflow and I don't understand why I'm wrong

[image]

Comment: Looks like whoever wrote this test has the common misconception that O means "worst case" and Ω means "best case". This is wrong. That is, the test has it wrong and your answers are correct, though two of the other answers (#3 and #5) are *also* correct statements, and #1 and #4 are *arguably* correct subject to how "its running time" should be interpreted (this often means either "worst case" or "average case" when not specified, but the question gives no information about the average case, so either #1 and #4 are correct or indeterminate. A strict formalist might say they are meaningless.)

Comment: On second reading the question appears to be a trick - it asks you to select which answers are *not* correct - but then it is ambiguous whether the feedback message means that you correctly selected the answers which are not correct, or that you incorrectly selected answers which are not incorrect. Either way the quiz is wrong, though.

Comment: @kaya3 I always thought of running time as a function of an input. Thus for a set of inputs of size n a set of values between lowest (best case) and greatest (worst case) possible values should be used. In that sense Omega is an asymptotic lower bound and O is an asymptotic upper bound for the values in this set, and when the tight forms of these bounds can be made equal we can write Theta. Therefore, in my opinion, #4 should be checked as wrong because Theta is indeterminate here (but I may be wrong in definition of running time). Otherwise, I agree with the quiz ie unchecked options are true

Comment: @absolute.madness If your set of inputs only includes inputs of one fixed size `n`, then you cannot do asymptotic analysis at all. Rather you need a set of inputs whose sizes `n` are unbounded, and then you define `T(n)` as being either the average, maximum (worst case) or minimum (best case) number of steps that the algorithm takes on an input of size `n` in that set. Your choice of how the function T(n) is defined is independent of your choice of whether to use O, omega or theta to describe the asymptotic behaviour of that function T(n). Note that you do *not* have a set of different ...

Comment: ... functions T(n) for each different input, and O vs. omega vs. theta is not about giving an upper and/or lower bound for *all* of the functions in some set - you are only describing the asymptotic bound for *a single function* which we have called T(n). The reason #1 and #4 could be considered meaningless is that it's not clear what function T(n) should be; but they could also be considered as referring to the worst case for the algorithm, since it is conventional to analyse the worst case unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @kaya3 no, n is not fixed, of course, it wouldn't make sense otherwise. I meant that if T(n) is not explicitly defined then I would think of input X as an implicit parameter T(n) = T(n, X) and interpret T(n) = Theta(F(n)) as the statement that both T_best(n) and T_worst(n) follow the same asymptotic because inputs of the size n would define a range of values for each n. But probably the emphasis of my comment should be that all other options, in my opinion, should be checked/unchecked as stated by the quiz authors. And only this one is arguable (I would consider it incorrect in my interp7n)

Comment: @kaya3 #1 doesn't depend on T(n) definition (worst/best/average) that differs it from #4

Comment: @absolute.madness Asymptotic complexity is defined for a function from the naturals to either the naturals or the reals - not for a function of two variables, and not for a multi-valued function which can have a range of different outputs for the same `n`. You have to have such a function T(n) before you can talk about its asymptotic complexity; the asymptotic complexity is about its behaviour as `n` grows, not about its behaviour for different inputs of size `n` (and this does not make any sense, because `T`'s input is simply a number, which we call `n`). #1 "doesn't depend on T(n)'s ...

Comment: ... definition" in the sense that it is true regardless of whether T(n) is the number of steps for an average, best or worst input of size `n`, but a strict formalist may still say that #1 is not a correct statement because it is meaningless, due to T(n) being unspecified. On the other hand, somebody who interprets #4 as being a meaningful statement should interpret it as being a statement about the worst case complexity, since that is the convention, in which case #4 is also a true statement. So #1 and #4 are either both meaningless or both true, though #4 requires knowing the convention.